# What is precedence of NETLOGON drive mapping vs Active Directory home directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-profile, netlogon

If a) a user's logon script maps a user's home drive to a home directory and the same homeDrive but different homeDirectory are set on the user object in Active Directory, which method takes precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login-script executes after the initial drive mapping, by my understanding. So if the Login script can't handle re-mapping an already mapped drive, it'll stay with what the AD object says it is. Though if the script CAN handle it, it will remap.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where this is documented?